# Jack London's punctuation choice of periods instead of semi-colons

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, periods

> The sled was without runners.  It was made of stout birch-bark, and
>   its full surface rested on the snow.  The front end of the sled was
>   turned up, like a scroll, in order to force down and under the bore of
>   soft snow that surged like a wave before it.

What difference would it make (?) if I punctuated that passage with a semicolon instead, as follows:

> The sled was without runners;  it was made of stout birch-bark, and its full surface rested on the snow;  the front end of the sled was turned up, like a scroll, in order to force down and under the bore of soft snow that surged like a wave before it.

All the sentences come together to describe the sled. Why do you think Mr. London picked the period?

Comment: Periods offer more finality to each individual sentence, really (pardon the pun) punctuating his description.

Comment: Although it's not, your long sentence feels like a run-on sentence when reading it. Sometimes simplicity is really elegance, and it's usually not a good idea to learn a language by challenging a good author's style. If you want to challenge an author, Dan Brown is a good one (to challenge, that is.)

Comment: "Good author" is subjective.

Comment: And style varies a lot. Compare, for example, James Joyce and Ernest Hemingway, both of whom are widely regarded as "good" authors.

Comment: I found the same preference for periods in George Orwell.