# Using periods instead of conjunctions or semi-colons

Tags: writing-style

Is there a name for this style when you prefer using periods instead of conjunctions or semi-colons?

For example, the following paragraph could use more conjunctions or semi-colons, but the author preferred periods:

> Winston made for the stairs. It was no use trying the lift. Even at the best of times it was seldom working, and at present the electric current was cut off during daylight hours.

This is similar to [Jack London's punctuation choice of periods instead of semi-colons](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233131/jack-londons-punctuation-choice-of-periods-instead-of-semi-colons#comment1441821_233131).

I read somewhere that punctuation style changed in English over the years. Nowadays, it's more common to use periods in English. I didn't find where I read that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often described as **staccato** (adjective, deriving from the [musical term](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/staccato)); or **parataxis** ([originally a Greek term](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parataxis)).

These days it's often associated with thriller/crime writers such as Lee Child and James Ellroy, but literary authors including Hemingway made use of it. [Here's](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CftRiJLZS7cC&lpg=PA81&ots=YgF0jPjDh5&dq=staccato%20prose%20style&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q=staccato%20prose%20style&f=false) a book on Hemingway, *The Critical Reception of Hemingway's The Sun Also Rises* by Peter L. Hays, which speaks of Hemingway's "staccato style", attributing the term to Herbert H Mosher, who identified (Hays writes): "short sentences in which the subject is immediately followed by verb, and in most, the first word is the subject; these sentences are either simple or complex, and there is frequent repetition of words. They average nine and a half words each".

According to Wikipedia, [parataxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis), is "a literary technique, in writing or speaking, that favors short, simple sentences, without conjunctions or with the use of coordinating, but not with subordinating conjunctions. It contrasts with syntaxis and hypotaxis."

It works well for pacy, rhythmic writing, or (as Hemingway often used it) to convey unspoken, underlying depths. It is certainly not something to look down on.

Comment: My favourite Hemingway spoof is by F Scott Fitzgerald. - _We were in a back-house in Juan-les-Pins. Bill had lost control of his sphincter muscles. There were
wet Matins in the rack beside the door. There were wet Eclaireurs de Nice in the rack over his head. When the King of Bulgaria came in Bill was just firing a burst that struck the old limeshit twenty feet down with a splat-tap. All the rest came just like that. The King of Bulgaria began to whirl round and round.  “The great thing in these affairs--” he said.  Soon he was whirling faster and faster. Then he was dead._